# Why does React not seem to recognize Heroku's PORT env variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, heroku, environment-variables

I am trying to deploy a frontend react application with a django backend. I am able to get Heroku's PORT environment variable just fine for the Django backend, but no matter what I do or try, `process.env.PORT` keeps returning undefined. I have tried adding a temporary variable that begins with REACT_APP that just reads the PORT variable in the procfile. Env files won't work because the PORT variable is dynamically allocated.

Every resource I have found have said to either try a .env file or exporting the variable, but like I said, that is unrealistic because Heroku dynamically allocates the port. Any ideas?

Comment: What's actually _serving_ the app? You shouldn't be using the dev server in production, rather serving the static outputs of the build process.

Comment: I am serving the static output of the build process. I couldn't get the nodejs buildpack to work, but I did get the react one to work: https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack

Comment: Serving it _with what_, though? `REACT_APP_` env vars are for CRA, at build time, they won't work at runtime. It looks like that buildpack uses NGINX, which should pick up the default env var. What makes you think it's not working - where are you trying to log the `process.env.PORT`?

Comment: I'm trying to communicate with my backend. It was deployed with the dynamic port that is defined by Heroku. I'm trying to log it in my react code when pressing a button to send a request to my backend. The variable is just undefined. It's undefined everywhere in react

Comment: Environment variables aren't available in the client. That's running in the user's browser, not the server. For that matter there isn't a Node process running on the server, either. Given you're using an NGINX buildpack the Django app is presumably in a different dyno entirely, you don't need to know which PORT it's bound to.

Comment: Okay, I think I had a misunderstanding about how it should work. Before in development, we used different ports. Sorry for the confusion; it's my first time every trying to deploy anything.

Comment: Please don't put answers in the question - if you no longer have the issue, I'd suggest deleting the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment variables aren't available in the client. That's running in the user's browser, not the server. For that matter there isn't a Node process running on the server, either. Given you're using an NGINX buildpack the Django app is presumably in a different dyno entirely, you don't need to know which PORT it's bound to. - @jonrsharpe

In the Heroku deployed environment, the project should be oriented such that the frontend will make a request to the backend through a specific url configuration, not through a different port call.